# Why is Xamarin.Android RecyclerView.Adapter not generic?

Tags: xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

I have noticed the `RecyclerView.Adapter` type is not generic in `Xamarin.Android`. Why is it so? It seems to be defined as generic in native Android according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html). Is there an underlying reason for this? Or is it some kind of backward compatiblity scenario?

Comment: Java style generics is require specific handling : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/limitations/#Generic_C_classes. Unlike .Net in Java they are a compile time construct not a runtime one. For a RecyclerView.Adapter, you can supply your  `ViewHolder` subclass as an inner-class, might make the code a little cleaner if you could use a generic class, but zero need for generics to actually implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create generic RecycleView in C# but not in java. In java you need to write code multiple times. That's why java android is worse even just simple event handler, Android Team Engineers are lazy to implements all data event handling because of the nature of java.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace XamarinAndroid.Basic.Core
{
    public class GenericRecyclerViewAdapter<T> : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// You can set this for different custom cardview
        /// </summary>
        public int CardViewResourceLayout { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<T> Items { get; private set; }
        public event EventHandler<RecyclerViewViewHolder> ItemViewTemplated;
        public GenericRecyclerViewAdapter(IEnumerable<T> items, int cardViewResourceLayout) : base()
        {
            this.Items = new ObservableCollection<T>(items);
            this.CardViewResourceLayout = cardViewResourceLayout;
            this.Items.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                catch { }
            };

        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            var itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(CardViewResourceLayout, parent, false);
#if DEBUG
            Log.Info("GenericRecyclerViewAdapter - ", CardViewResourceLayout.ToString());
#endif
            RecyclerViewViewHolder vh = new RecyclerViewViewHolder(itemView);
            return vh;
        }        

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            RecyclerViewViewHolder vh = holder as RecyclerViewViewHolder;
            vh.ItemPosition = position;
            vh.TemplateView.Tag = position;
            vh.TemplateView.Click -= TemplateView_Click;
            vh.TemplateView.Click += TemplateView_Click;
            this.ItemViewTemplated?.Invoke(this, vh);
        }
        public event EventHandler<T> ItemClicked;
        private void TemplateView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var position = (int)((View)sender).Tag;
            this.ItemClicked?.Invoke(this, this.Items[position]);
        }

        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get { return this.Items.Count; }
        }
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return base.GetItemId(position);
        }
    }

    public class RecyclerViewViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public View TemplateView { get; private set; }
        public int ItemPosition { get;  set; }

        public RecyclerViewViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
        {
            // Locate and cache view references:
            this.TemplateView = itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

Assigning data to each view

```
var recyclerViewToday = this.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerViewToday);
            var layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            recyclerViewToday.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            var  adapter = new GenericRecyclerViewAdapter<FavoriteModel>(previousList, Resource.Layout.recent_list_item);
            adapter.ItemViewTemplated += (d, holder) =>
            {
                var indicate = holder.ItemView.FindViewById<View>(Resource.Id.indicatorItemmRec);
                indicate.SetBackgroundColor(ColorHelper.GetRandomLightColor());

                (holder.ItemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.wordTxtRec)).Text = adapter.Items[holder.ItemPosition].Word;

                var textView = (holder.ItemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.definitionTxtRec));
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(previousList[holder.ItemPosition].Definition))
                    textView.Text = previousList[holder.ItemPosition].Definition;
                else
                    textView.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;
            };
            recyclerViewToday.SetAdapter(adapter);
```

Result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clean, Generic and Reusable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Text.Style;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Util.Zip;
using ActionMenuView = Android.Support.V7.Widget.ActionMenuView;

namespace Android.Basic.Core
{
    public class GenericRecyclerViewAdapter<T> : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// You can set this for different custom cardview
        /// </summary>
        private int CardViewResourceLayout { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<T> Items { get; private set; }
        public  event EventHandler<RecyclerViewViewHolder> ItemViewTemplated;
        public RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
        public GenericRecyclerViewAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView, IEnumerable<T> items, int cardViewResourceLayout, bool isList = true, bool isVertical = true) : base()
        {
            
            if(isList)
            {
                var vertical = isVertical ? LinearLayoutManager.Vertical : LinearLayoutManager.Horizontal;
                layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.Context, vertical, false);
            }
            else
            {
                var vertical = isVertical ? GridLayoutManager.Vertical : GridLayoutManager.Horizontal;
                layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(recyclerView.Context, 3, vertical, false);
            }
            recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            this.Items = new ObservableCollection<T>(items);
            this.CardViewResourceLayout = cardViewResourceLayout;
            this.Items.CollectionChanged += delegate
            {
                this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            };
           
        }
        
        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            var itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(CardViewResourceLayout, parent, false);
#if DEBUG
            Log.Info("GenericRecyclerViewAdapter - ", CardViewResourceLayout.ToString());
#endif
            RecyclerViewViewHolder vh = new RecyclerViewViewHolder(itemView);
            return vh;
        }        
        
        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            RecyclerViewViewHolder vh = holder as RecyclerViewViewHolder;
            vh.ItemPosition = position;
            vh.TemplateView.Tag = position;
            vh.TemplateView.Click -= TemplateView_Click;
            vh.TemplateView.Click += TemplateView_Click;
            ItemViewTemplated?.Invoke(this, vh);
        }
        public event EventHandler<T> ItemClicked;
     
        private void TemplateView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var position = (int)((View)sender).Tag;
            this.ItemClicked?.Invoke(sender, this.Items[position]);
          
        }

        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get { return this.Items.Count; }
        }
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return base.GetItemId(position);
        }

    }

    public class RecyclerViewViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder, View.IOnCreateContextMenuListener,
        IMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener
    {
        public View TemplateView { get; private set; }
        public int ItemPosition { get;  set; }
        public event EventHandler<MenuInfo> ContextMenuCreated;
        public event EventHandler<object> MenuItemClicked;
        public MenuInfo MenuInfo { get; private set; }
        public object Data { get; set; }
        public RecyclerViewViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
        {
            // Locate and cache view references:
            this.TemplateView = itemView;
            this.TemplateView.SetOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
           
        }

        public void OnCreateContextMenu(IContextMenu menu, View v, IContextMenuContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
        {
            MenuInfo = new MenuInfo(menu, v, menuInfo);
            ContextMenuCreated?.Invoke(this, MenuInfo);

        }
        private Android.Views.MenuInflater menuInflater = null;
        /// <summary>
        /// After ContextMenuCreated 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="resourcemenu"></param>
        public void InflateMenu(int resourcemenu, SpannableString titleColor = null, object dta = null)
        {
            if (dta != null)
                this.Data = dta;
            if (this.TemplateView.Context is AppCompatActivity activity)
            {
                menuInflater = activity.MenuInflater;

            }
            else if (this.TemplateView.Context is Activity activity2)
            {
                menuInflater = activity2.MenuInflater;
            }
            var contextMenu = this.MenuInfo.ContextMenu;
            contextMenu.Clear();
            menuInflater.Inflate(resourcemenu, contextMenu);
            var num = contextMenu.Size() - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
            {
                var men = contextMenu.GetItem(i);
                if(titleColor != null)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {                       
                        men.SetTitle(titleColor);
                        men.SetChecked(true);
                    }
                }
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    men.SetOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
                }

            }
        }
        
        public bool OnMenuItemClick(IMenuItem item)
        {
            this.MenuItemClicked?.Invoke(item, this.Data);
            return true;
        }

        public float PosX;
        public float PosY;
        
    }
    
    public class MenuInfo
    {
        public IContextMenu ContextMenu { get; }
        public View View { get; }
        public IContextMenuContextMenuInfo ContextMenuInfo { get; }
        public MenuInfo(IContextMenu contextMenu, View view, IContextMenuContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
        {
            this.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
            this.View = view;
            this.ContextMenuInfo = menuInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = context.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recycler);
            var viewAdapter = new Android.Basic.Core.GenericRecyclerViewAdapter<StorageFile>(recyclerView, files, Resource.Layout.main_item);
            viewAdapter.ItemViewTemplated += (dd, holder) =>
            {
                //CardView
                CardView cardView = holder.ItemView.FindViewById<CardView>(Resource.Id.CategorycardView);
                cardView.SetCardBackgroundColor(ThemeHelper.IsDark ? Color.ParseColor("#303030") : Color.White);
                var indicator = holder.ItemView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.indicator);
                indicator.SetBackgroundColor(ThemeHelper.IsDark ? ColorHelper.GetRandomLightColor() : ColorHelper.GetRandomDarkColor());
                var file = files[holder.ItemPosition];
                var itemIcon = holder.ItemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.itemIcon);
                var icon = file.GetFileThumbnail();
                if (icon != null)
                {
                    itemIcon.SetImageBitmap(icon);
                }
                TextView itemName = holder.ItemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.itemName);
                itemName.Text = file.DisplayName;
                itemName.SetTextColor(textColor);

               
            };
            viewAdapter.ItemClicked += (dd, ff) =>
            {
                var checkBttn = (dd as View).FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.check_boxBttn);
                
               
            };
            recyclerView.SetAdapter(viewAdapter);
```